Flutter GetX package same page transition issue
here is my dependency code.
import 'package:get/get.dart';

import 'movies.dart';

class DiMoviesDetail extends Bindings {
  @override
  void dependencies() {
    Get.lazyPut<MoviesDetailRemoteDatasource>(
        () => MoviesDetailRemoteDatasourceImpl(),
        fenix: true);
    Get.lazyPut<MoviesDetailLocalDatasource>(
        () => MoviesDetailLocalDatasourcImp(),
        fenix: true);
    Get.lazyPut<MoviesDetailRepository>(() => MoviesDetailRepositoryImp(),
        fenix: true);
    Get.lazyPut(() => MoviesDetailRemote(), fenix: true);
    Get.lazyPut(() => MovieDetailLocal(), fenix: true);
    Get.lazyPut(() => MoviesDetailUsecase(), fenix: true);
    Get.lazyPut(() => MoviesImagesUsecase(), fenix: true);
    Get.lazyPut(() => MoviesCollectionDetailUsecase(), fenix: true);

    Get.create(() => MoviesDetailController(),);
  }

This part is the route code.

import 'package:get/get.dart';

import '../../lib.dart';

class RouteManager {
  static appRoutes() => [
        GetPage(
          name: RouteConstants.SPLASH,
          bindings: [DiDiscovery(), DiMovieList()],
          page: () => const Filmolog(),
        ),
        GetPage(
          name: RouteConstants.MOVIEDETAIL,
          bindings: [DiMoviesDetail(),],
          page: () => const MoviesDetailPage(),
          transition: Transition.rightToLeft,
        ),
      ];
}


This part is the GetMaterialApp code.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScreenUtilInit(
        designSize: const Size(360, 690),
        builder: (context, child) {
          return GetMaterialApp(
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            title: 'Filmolog',
            translations: LocalizationsApp(),
            locale: Get.deviceLocale,
            fallbackLocale: const Locale('tr', 'TR'),
            theme: getApplicationTheme(),
            themeMode: ThemeMode.dark,
            localizationsDelegates: const [
              GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
              GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
              GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
            ],            
            supportedLocales: const [
              Locale('tr'),
              Locale('en'),
            ],
            initialBinding: DiApp(),
            initialRoute: RouteConstants.SPLASH,
            getPages: RouteManager.appRoutes(),
          );
        });
  }
}

I'm doing my transitions like this.
GestureDetector(
                      child: PosterAndTitleWidget(
                        posterPath: result[index].posterPath,
                        releaseDate: result[index].releaseDate,
                        title: result[index].title,
                        voteAverage: AppSettings.voteAverageString(
                            result[index].voteAverage!),
                      ),
                      onTap: () {
                     
                        Get.toNamed(RouteConstants.MOVIEDETAIL,
                            preventDuplicates: false,
                            arguments: result[index].id!);
                      },
                    );

The user comes to the movie details page. While on the details page, they open the same details page again. I'm not having any issues with get.create regarding this. However, when the user closes and reopens the screen on their phone, the previous movie details disappear and the last opened movie detail is shown repeatedly.
What I'm expecting from you is that when the user reopens the phone, at least the application starts from the root page ("/")

You can try to use next:
class LifecycleEventHandler extends WidgetsBindingObserver {

  @override
  Future<void> didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) async {
    switch (state) {
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
         //do something here, for example
         Get.offAll(() => Home());
      case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
      case AppLifecycleState.detached:
          //do something here: 
     
    }
  }
}

You should register the observer in your main.dart or somewhere:
WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(lifecycleEventHandler);
You also can create a designated <bool>controller whose state will change when
AppLifecycleState changes. Then you can do some UI/navigation logic in your widgets depending on controller state.

Thank you for your answer. so when you look at my codes, am I using getx wrong? I could not provide the getfactory feature in the getit package with getcreate in getx. do you have any information about this?

https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/issues/3048
Two options:

Get.create is used with GetWidget.
Use tag.


Well, when the user turns off the phone screen, the same page is constantly displayed. So it opens the film detail page after the homepage. While on the same page, it opens the same film detail page again. Maybe it does this many times. When the user turns off the screen and turns it back on after a while, all the film detail page stacks are the last page opened. Can I get rid of this problem if I use tag or getwidget?
